# Are there any benefits to Session Storage over Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

Apart from being non persistent and scoped only to the current window, are there any benefits (performance, data access, etc) to Session Storage over Local Storage?

Comment: @robert - I believe you're incorrect.  From http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/ sessionStorage is scoped to the "top-level browsing context", meaning it is unique to each  browser tab / window.  localStorage is scoped to the origin, however, meaning it's shared across all pages on the same origin.

Comment: Re: Performance http://jsperf.com/localstorage-vs-sessionstorage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between localStorage, sessionStorage, session and cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies)

Answer (score 1048, accepted):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) both extend [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage). There is no difference between them except for the intended "non-persistence" of `sessionStorage`.

That is, the data stored in `localStorage` **persists until explicitly deleted**. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site.

For `sessionStorage`, **changes are only available per tab.** Changes made are saved and available for the current page **in that tab** until it is closed. Once it is closed, the stored data is deleted.

Comment: there's a broader discussion that you may find helpful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookie

Comment: if you save some data in storage under http, you will not be able to retrieve it at https

Comment: i tested this on Chrome  v41.x and it seems that the above statement about https is not true: localStorage retains its stored data.

Comment: SessionStorage survives over page reloads and restores, but opening a new tab/window will initiate a new session.

Answer (score 183):

The only difference is that they have different expiration times.

- `sessionStorage` will only be accessible while and by the window that created it is open.
- `localStorage` lasts until you delete it or the user deletes it.

Let's say that you wanted to save a login username and password you would want to use `sessionStorage` over `localStorage` for security reasons (i.e. another person accessing their account at a later time).

But if you wanted to save a user's settings on their machine you would  probably want `localStorage`.

In conclusion

- `localStorage` - use for long term use.
- `sessionStorage` - use when you need to store something that changes or something temporary

Answer (score 120):

Few other points which might be helpful to understand differences between local and session storage

1. Both local storage and session storage are scoped to document origin, so

   ```
   https://mydomain.example/ 
   http://mydomain.example/
   https://mydomain.example:8080/
   ```

   All of the above URL's will ***not*** share the same storage. (Notice path of the web page does not affect the web storage)
2. Session storage is different even for the document with same origin policy open in different tabs, so same web page open in two different tabs ***cannot*** share the same session storage.
3. Both local and session storage are also scoped by ***browser vendors***. So storage data saved by IE cannot be read by Chrome or FF.

Comment: No, same sessionStorage share  between http and https  but localStorage not.

Comment: If you set sessionStorage in https origin first, it will be available in http but if you create sessionStore in http then will not be available in http

Comment: @Shahdat, did you mean "then will not be available in https" (notice the s)?

Comment: @DanielWerner yes,  if you create sessionStore in http then will not be available in https.

Answer (score 36):

The main difference between `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` is that `sessionStorage` is unique per tab. If you close the tab the `sessionStorage` gets deleted, `localStorage` does not. Also you cannot communicate between tabs :)

Another subtle difference is that for example on Safari (8.0.3) `localStorage` has a limit of 2551 k characters but `sessionStorage` has *unlimited storage*

On Chrome (v43) both `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` are limited to 5101 k characters (no difference between normal / incognito mode)

On Firefox both `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` are limited to 5120 k characters (no difference between normal / private mode )

No difference in speed whatsoever :)

There's also a problem with Mobile Safari and Mobile Chrome, Private Mode Safari & Chrome have a maximum space of 0KB

Comment: limited to 5101 k characters? so.. 5.101 million characters?

Comment: @Zze Yes, 1 character is usually 1 byte hence 5 million characters is 5Mb worth of storage.

Comment: @BasimKhajwal That is 5MB. Bytes, not bits.

Comment: Can you please add source to what you have mentioned?

Comment: @Mukus, there is no source, I ran tests myself, and had an issue with Private Mode Safari for having localStorage but having no space there and my polyfill wouldn't trigger since localStorage existed, but the script failed since it couldn't store anything there. You can test too using this tool - http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/

Answer (score 18):

`sessionStorage` is the same as `localStorage`, except that it stores the data for only one session, and it will be removed when the user closes the browser window that created it.

Comment: Did you mean the *tab* instead of the *window*?

Comment: The browser treats both tabs and windows the same way.

Answer (score 9):

> - `sessionStorage` maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session (as long as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores)
> - `localStorage` does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.

I took this from [`Web Storage API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Answer (score 7):

performance wise, my (crude) measurements found no difference on 1000 writes and reads

security wise, intuitively it would seem the localStore might be shut down before the sessionStore, but have no  concrete evidence - maybe someone else does?

functional wise, concur with digitalFresh above

Comment: regarding page load performance: Both, sessionStorage and localStorage are initiated and populated out of the page-load-render cycle. Therefore the toll on initial page load time is not measurable from within the browser.

Answer (score 5):

Ya session storage and local storage are same in behaviour except one that is local storage will store the data until and unless the user delete the cache and cookies and session storage data will retain in the system until we close the session i,e until we close the session storage created window.

Answer (score 5):

The advantage of the session storage over local storage, in my opinion, is that it has [unlimited capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840976/how-large-is-html5-session-storage?answertab=votes#tab-top) in Firefox, and won't persist longer than the session. (Of course it depends on what your goal is.)

Answer (score 4):

Late answer but felt to add some points here.

Session storage will be available for specific tab where as we can use Local storage through out the browser. Both are default to same origin and we can also store values manually with key, value pairs (value must be string).

Once tab (session) of the browser is closed then Session storage ***will be cleared*** on that tab, where as in case of Local storage we need to ***clear it explicitly***. Maximum storage limit respectively `5MB` and `10MB`.

We can save and retrieve the data like below,

**To Save:**

```
sessionStorage.setItem('id', noOfClicks);   // localStorage.setItem('id', noOfClicks);

sessionStorage.setItem('userDetails', JSON.stringify(userDetails));   // if it's object
```

**To Get:**

```
sessionStorage.getItem('id');    // localStorage.getItem('id');

User user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("userDetails")) as User;  // if it's object
```

**To Modify:**

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('id');    // localStorage.removeItem('id');

sessionStorage.clear();   // localStorage.clear();
```

**P.S:** `getItem()` also return back the data as string and we ***need convert it*** into *JSON format* to access if it's object.

You can read more about Browser Storages here..

1. [Difference between localStorage, sessionStorage and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44358718/9764133)
2. [localstorage-vs-sessionstorage](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/localstorage-vs-sessionstorage-c22164aff067)

Answer (score 3):

**Local storage:** It keeps store the user information data without expiration date this data will not be deleted when user closed the browser windows it will be available for day, week, month and year.

```
//Set the value in a local storage object
localStorage.setItem('name', myName);

//Get the value from storage object
localStorage.getItem('name');

//Delete the value from local storage object
localStorage.removeItem(name);//Delete specifice obeject from local storege
localStorage.clear();//Delete all from local storege
```

**Session Storage:** It is same like local storage date except it will delete all windows when browser windows closed by a web user.

```
//set the value to a object in session storege
sessionStorage.myNameInSession = "Krishna";
```

Read More [Click](http://developerstips.com/html5-web-storage-html-api/)