# How large is HTML5 session storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

Although the [size of localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284) has been addressed in detail and there is a [online test for it](http://arty.name/localstorage.html), I was wondering what the maximum size of [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) is for the common browsers?

Comment: As mentioned in some deleted answers comments http://web.archive.org/web/20160216064847/http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/ is good resource

Answer (score 75, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/), Firefox’s and Safari’s storage limit is 5MB per domain, Internet Explorer’s limit is 10 MB per domain.

However, according to [this site which tests your web browser local storage capabilities](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/), on my machine:

```
Browser        LocalStorage         SessionStorage
-------        ------------         --------------
Chrome              5M                   5M
Firefox             5M                Unlimited
IE11                5M                   5M
```

Also, note the handy chart at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks Robert. What about Chrome? Same as Safari? That link is rather dated at 2009. Have the browsers updated this since then?

Comment: According to [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage), sessionStorage is limited only by available system memory in Chrome.  However, see my answer update.

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage) explains that about Chrome too...

Comment: RIP IE: you should remove it

Answer (score -6):

The amount able to be stored varries from browser to browser with IE being able to store up to a couple MB. It is also good to note that there is a vulnerabilty that allows an unlimited amount of data to be stored.