# Focus the first input on load only if no input is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, focus

I'm trying to set a default focus for all the pages of my site but without changing the focus on page reload.

I mean:

- User opens a page.
- Focus is automatically set on the 1st input.
- User changes focus to the 3rd input.
- User refreshes the page.
- Focus must not change to the 1st input again. (This is the requirement I fail to accomplish).

My current code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($(':focus').length === 0) {
        $(':input:not([type="hidden"]):first').focus();
    }

});
```

The condition is true every time!

Comment: Why would you assume the state would be saved if you refresh the page?

Comment: I have a solution but you have to use localStorage for it,is it ok?

Comment: @Zenith My browser saves the focus when I refresh or go back. Is that impossible to detect with javascript?

Comment: @AdriánLópez Not impossible. I think MESSIAH should post an answer for you.

Comment: @MESSIAH Never used that before, it's like a local html5 DB or something, isn't it.

Comment: Cookies vs LocalStorage... both can provide the same thing in this regard, that is if you want maximum compatibility.

Comment: yes,its very simple and the you just have to use localstorage.setitem and localstorage.getitem

Comment: @MESSIAH Could you post it then?

Comment: is it ok,if I do it with javascript?

Comment: @MESSIAH Yeah... why wouldn't be?

Comment: give me 10 min,posting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready({

window.onload=function(){
if(session.Storage.getItem("text3")){//if key= text3 is set,then change the focus to 3rd text box.
$('#your3rdTextID').focus();
}


$('#your3rdTextID').focus(function(){
    session.Storaage.setItem("text3","selected")//here you set the key as text3 and value as selected for later use.
});


});
```

You can provide with your own custom conditions.This is just a small example.Hope it helped you.Good luck with your project.

LINK-->[HTML5 Local storage vs. Session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/local-storage-vs-session-storage)

LINK-->http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Do I have a different `session.Storage` for each of the pages or just one for the whole site? Do you know?

Comment: well,its pretty simple.session persist till the close of your browser until the browser is closed.Its valid to all your pages within the website.
LOCALSTORAGE persist even after browser close.

You can clear local storage with localstorage.clear().

Comment: mm I would need a dictionary/map like with the cookie solution

Comment: There are some other methods as well---persist.js  and jstorage.Google them for more informaton.Http are stateless,using web storage or cookies or any other js library serves you requirement.

Comment: @AdriánLópez: dictionary/map?

Comment: @AdriánLópez, mind your browsers. If your application relies on legacy support, local storage is not the answer, although a great alternative.

Comment: IE7+ supports all webstorage.
Obviously,rest of them all do quite a good job.Surprisingly,IE leads in localstorage giving maximum of 10 mb storage.

Comment: [Here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html#Overview) it says that the localStorage scope is only the window/tab. By dictionary I meant that I want to store it for every form in my site. So if I have a separated storage per page, I wouldn't need to define an structure to associate the value to the page where the focus belongs.

Comment: If you want IE7 support,go with jstorage which is a new emerging js or  go with cookies as suggested by zamnuts.

Comment: @zamnuts it's for my final graduation project, not for the real world so I don't really need much legacy support.

Comment: if you want IE7+,I would say prefer local storage as they have more storing capacity than cookies(4kb for each cookies with per domain setting up to 20 cookies).No such restriction on local.Storage..Besides its very simple to learn!!!

Comment: Well, it's only for remembering the focus (for now :D), even 1kb would be more than enough. But I'll take that into account just in case I need more capacity for other requirements.

Answer (score 2):

This will work (tested in latest Chrome, IE7 and IE10). Sets a cookie on focus remembering the last focused element, if not, it defaults to the first. It relies on [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) ([usage explained in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458728/1481489)). Here is the full HTML+JS source of a minimal working example. Consider changing the cookie name and the input selector (currently `'input'`):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>focus test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $input = $('input'), // get all the inputs
                cookieName = 'lastInputFocusIndex', // for consistency
                lastIndex = $.cookie(cookieName) || 0; // get the last known index, otherwise default to zero
            $input.on('focus',function(){ // when any of the selected inputs are focused
                if ( $(this).attr('type') !== 'submit' ) {
                    $.cookie(cookieName,$input.index(this)); // get their index in the $input list and store it
                }
            });
            $input.eq(lastIndex).focus(); // when the page loads, auto focus on the last known index (or the default of 0)
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" action="">
    <p><input type="text" name="first" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="second" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="third" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Go" /></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could write your own raw cookies instead of using the cookie helper jQuery plugin; I used it to simplify things.

Comment: So I would need a cookie for each page with a form in my site, right?

Comment: @AdriánLópez With this exact implementation, yes. However, it could be enhanced: if you have a generic cookie name and store an object in it (use the page name as a key, e.g. `{'home':INDEX,'about':INDEX,'contact':INDEX}`, then you can pull it specifically for a page but keep them all in the same place (minimizing cookie overload). I did not specifically target that use case since it was not mentioned in your original question scope.