# Yii : Session Storage, am I in the right direction

Tags: performance, session, caching, yii

I am trying to implement session storage based on what I found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/local-storage-vs-session-storage) post. I am planning to store base data from different tables in session to increase performance by doing various validations at client. I am planning to use [Yii: CHttpSession](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession) and jQuery to access the session data. I am already using APC but I feel this need because all the data from APC is coming from server whereas I need to do the validations once all the data is at client because it will save me many server trips. I need to make sure that I am thinking on the right lines and in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHttpSession` is a class that implements server side session storage that is not accessible to javascript.

APC is also entirely server side, if you intend to cache data at the client end, look the local (and session) storage techniques available in javascript with HTML5 (although be aware that this will limit the availability of your site on older browsers). jQuery has good integration for both of these.

http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.localStorage

http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.sessionStorage

Another possibility would be opening a socket to your server where you can rapidly query the server to check for changes and update your local storage when you find some. This combined with a local cache would make for a fairly powerful app, as sockets are persistent connections and as such will allow for lower overhead communication. Although they do require a little work, as far as I know there is no jQuery support for them yet, and you will likely want to program the server side code in something that also better supports persistent connections (C or java for example).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Many thanks, I will work in the directions you have pointed out. Cheers.