# $window.sessionStorage value not accecble in other tab in same window?

Tags: angularjs, session, local-storage

I am using `$window.sessionStorage.isLoggedIn` variable for handling `logged in` in `angularjs` as follows,

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/components/main/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardController',
            resolve: {
                loggedIn: function ($location, $window) {
                    console.info($window.sessionStorage.isLoggedIn)
                    if (!$window.sessionStorage.isLoggedIn) {
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                }
            };
        })
```

Normally it is working fine,but when I am opening my web app in new tab in same browser,the value of `$window.sessionStorage.isLoggedIn` will be undefined and redirecting to `login` page, meanwhile in my previous tab,my app is working as logged in . Why it is happening? Local storage is tab independent?

Answer (score 1):

The value of `sessionStorage` does not persist between tabs. You can use `localStorage` to do it.

A weakness of the `localStorage` is that you cannot set an expire date for it. So in some cases the use of cookies is the best solution for storing data.

So, I prefer to use [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies):

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

To learn more about localStorage and sessionStorage check out this link: [HTML5 Local storage vs. Session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage)