# authentication and authorization in ajax call

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, authentication, authorization

`Request object` and `response object` are not available in `ajax` call. And Gmail and many other sites use Ajax and authentication and authorization.

My question is: how they authenticate?

since authentication information mostly stored in `Session` object` and Session object is not available in ajax call.

I am from `asp.net` background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is just a way for your web page to make HTTP requests. HTTP requests can be authenticated in several [different ways](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml).

Most modern APIs use a bearer authentication scheme (like `[OAuth2][2]`), where they acquire a token from an authorization server and add it to the request in the Authorization HTTP header, like:

```
Authorization: bearer <base64(token)>
```

Comment: where can I place token in html ?

Comment: You keep the token in a JavaScript variable or store it in session storage.

Comment: do u mean local storage in html5?

Comment: You can use either one, but I would recommend session storage in this case. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5523140/18044