# Submit a Login form using data received in another form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a login form in my webpage. How can I access data in the login form in my webpage and inject the received data in another third party login form which i don't have any end level access and auto-click submit button.

Comment: You can serialize the form data using $("#frmStudent").serialize();
So if you need to use that serialized data in some other page, use session storage or local storage.
$("#frmStudent").serialize(); returns the string, so place as it is in local storage, while retrieving the values from that string use string string.split("&") method you will get array

Comment: can u provide me tutorial link or something

Comment: [Serialize](https://www.formget.com/javascript-serialize/).
[Storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage)

Check those links

Comment: what i need is to submit data obtained in a login page in my website to another persons webiste login page and submit the button in his page automatically

Comment: Little confusing your question, if possible try to share us your code what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing, so let me try to understand: 
you are trying to carry the information received from a form throughout multiple ".php" pages? 
İf so, you can use the $_SESSION command. More information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp), however this is briefly how you can use it. 
You start with a

```
<?php
session_start(); 

$_SESSION["information"] = informationToCarry;

?>
```

By opening with a session_start at the beginning of every page, you will be able to retrieve that information with the same syntax

```
$_SESSION["information"];
```

Please be a little more clear next time,
Good Luck