# can we use both session and local storage in angularjs?

Tags: local-storage, session-variables

Can we use both local storage and session storage at the same time??[storage types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsTY5.png)

Comment: what happens when you try?

Comment: its not depend on angular, it is feature of HTML 5

Comment: Please do more research on the session and local storage. It's HTML feature.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` and `sessionStorage` both extend `Storage`. We can use both of them in our application. But, there is no difference between them except for the intended "non-persistence" of `sessionStorage`.

That is, the data stored in `localStorage` persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site.

For `sessionStorage`, changes are only available per window (or tab in browsers like Chrome and Firefox). Changes made are saved and available for the current page, as well as future visits to the site **on the same window**. Once the window is closed, the storage is deleted.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5523174/8317956