# Query regarding Localstorage and Sessionstorage in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-services

Is it safe to save token in sessionstorage, which I get from service call in angular2? I was used localstorage, but it can be hacked. If I simply write token from login page to localstorage manually in the browser, it automatically logins, which is a big bug. So any solution?

Comment: what type of token are we talking about here. what is it's purpose in your app?

Comment: read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage

Comment: I know that link @Harshakj89 .I know how to use sessionstorage.

Comment: @AbhishekPratihari I found that answer to your question is there. because I found that post useful when I had a question like yours.

Comment: Hello @lakshay .In my app,token was used. When i will login ,it will generate a token in server,which will later used for getting data using that token. Which i have to send with some variables. Now the thing is,token,if i will manually write some token in browser localstorage,it just automatically logged in.

Comment: after getting the data using the generated token will you need your token again or it's work is over?

Comment: @lakshay i need that token.If i will delete that token,then it will automatically  logged out. Note that the token i am getting is in HEX.

Comment: ok...so if you don't want to use local storage why don't you create an angular service and save the token there and then use the service to get the token wherever you need it.

Comment: or you could save the token in localstorage using security algorithms like HMAC-SHA. Using this your token will be more secured than storing it directly.

Comment: ok,thanks.I will try both the cases.

Comment: @lakshay If i store the token in a service,is it available ,if i refresh the page? Any suggestion.

Comment: yes a service will hold your value until you manually override its value.

Comment: @lakshay I was just checked that,if i change the name of token,like using any encrypt method,and use in the app. Everytime i start a session  it will be named newly.That is the solution.

Comment: so the secong case workd for you i guess.