# sessionStorage.get() - get current key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session-storage

I have a current sessionStorage in place. 
The .set method is working correctly.

The problem is the key it's not fixed. it's being created with the array of the first product I click.

like this: 
[image]

Like this, I can't have a key value to use the .get method in another page.

This is my JS.

```js
$('.go-to-bag').click(function() {
  var productId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  var productName = $(this).parent().attr('product-name');
  var productQty = $(this).prev().val();
  var productLWeight = $(this).parent().attr('product-weight');
  var productPesoBruto = $(this).parent().attr('product-pesobruto');
  var productPrice = $(this).parent().attr('product-price');
  var productPricesemiva = $(this).parent().attr('product-pricesemiva');

  var newList = new Object();

  if (sessionStorage.newShoppingList) {
    newShoppingList = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('newShoppingList'));
  } else {
    newShoppingList = []
  }

  newShoppingList.push({
    productId,
    productName,
    productQty,
    productPrice,
    productPricesemiva,
    productLWeight,
    productPesoBruto
  });

  sessionStorage.setItem('newShoppingList', JSON.stringify(newShoppingList));

  var retrievedObject = sessionStorage.getItem('newShoppingList');
  console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

});
```

So, I can I get the key so i can use .get method and retrive the value inserted in another page?

Comment: The key is `newShoppingList`, what do you mean it's not fixed?

Comment: I mean that, it's supposed to be newShoppingList. 
But instead, everytime I click on a product, the key changes. 

You can the it here: 
https://www.develop2you.com/equador/category.php?id=3&ids=3

Comment: I tried it, every time I clicked on `SACO DE COMPRAS` it updated the `newShoppingList` item.

Comment: Please use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to show all your relevant code here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: so do you have any suggestion for me to use the .get method on another page?

Comment: when i use on the console: sessionStorage.get(newShoppingList); I get that newShoppingList it's not defined

Comment: You're looking for `sessionStorage.get('newShoppingList')` there :) .

Answer (score 0):

The example that you've given us is correct.
At this point I would review if that is truly the only place that you call `.setItem`.

Also, that last question makes me wonder -- are you intending to use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`? [See this link for the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage)

[W3Schools Web Storage Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: He's using EcmaScript-6 shorthand. `{a, b, c}` is short for `{a: a, b: b, c:c}`

Comment: Oh, that's supported now? Great to know! Edited.

Comment: I suspect he really does want to use session storage. It's a shopping cart for a retail site, so he just wants it to last while the user is on the site.

Comment: Well, let's put it, in a different way: 

I want to store the values from the product on this page: 
https://www.develop2you.com/equador/category.php?id=3&ids=26

and then display them on this page (right side column - like a shoplist): 
https://www.develop2you.com/equador/billing.php

So, when i'm talking about sessionstorage.get I want to be able to take the values stored in the sessionStorage and display each product in that list. 

The reason for sessionstorage it's that i don't want to store any value when the user close the tab.

Comment: Possibly. It's just this question that threw me off.
`So, I can I get the key so i can use .get method and retrive the value inserted in another page?`
If he can't retrieve the value from another page I thought he might not quite be getting the difference... **shrug**

Comment: when i use on the console: 
sessionStorage.get(newShoppingList); 
I get that newShoppingList it's not defined

Comment: You're looking for `sessionStorage.get('newShoppingList');` there.