# Difference between localstorage and session

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, passport.js

I have created user authentication with passport local strategy and i use session. Everytime the user logged in session is stored in database and the browser. In my frontend can use the user.id to store it in local storage as a key or token ?

Comment: if this answered  your question, please mark as solved :)

Comment: I understand the difference. My question is approciate to store the user.id as the token or key for the localStorage on my react App

Comment: you can use both, it depends on how you want to make it. your decision should come from the understanding of the differences between the 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Local storage vs. Session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage)

Answer (score 4):

**LocalStorage**

Stores data with no expiration date, and gets cleared only through JavaScript, or clearing the Browser cache / Locally Stored Data
Storage limit is the maximum amongst the three (including cookies)

**SessionStorage**

The sessionStorage object stores data only for a session, meaning that the data is stored until the browser (or tab) is closed.
Data is never transferred to the server.
Storage limit is larger than a cookie (at least 5MB).