# Asp.net Webforms has a Session.SessionId is there an equivalent of this in Blazor?

Tags: c#, webforms, blazor, session-variables

I have an existing webforms applications which logs the SessionId ,I am converting the entire appplication to blazor and was wondering if there was an equivalent of this session id??

Comment: Take a look at  https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-i-store-session-data-in-server-side-blazor    AND   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server     AND   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913396/how-to-store-session-data-in-server-side-blazor     AND   https://tutorialslink.com/Articles/How-to-use-Sessions-in-Blazor-Application/2057

Comment: Server App, my companies websites is currently in webforms and we are looking  move to .netcore and blazor we use the session Id to track user activities, And I totally agree with your google translate analogy not at all I good idea (Ive found out the hard way ;) )

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will definitely take you up om that offer if the opportunity arises : )

Comment: The circuit Id seems to be a good option ,problem is that it changes after refresh...