# Best Approach for Preserving User Input Across Blazor Pages in ASP.NET Core Application with User-Specific Data Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, blazor

I have an ASP.NET Core application with Blazor pages featuring a sidebar containing five URLs. Each page consists of 15 input boxes. I need the input data to persist after page refreshes or when switching between URLs. Additionally, this data should be accessible in the backend for calculations. Considering the presence of a login page, the input values and backend data should be specific to the logged-in user. I've considered using server-side session storage, but I'm unsure if this is the most elegant solution. What are your suggestions for achieving this functionality?

Specifically, I'm looking for recommendations on how to:

1. Preserve input data across page refreshes and URL switches.
2. Store the input data securely and efficiently on the server, ensuring it's only accessible to the logged-in user.
3. Maintain a connection between the input data in the frontend and its corresponding representation in the backend for calculations.
4. Explore alternatives to server-side session storage if it's not the optimal solution for this scenario.

Any insights, recommendations, or best practices would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I must admit that I haven't delved into implementing any specific solutions yet. While I'm aware of the concept of server-side session storage and browser local storage, I haven't attempted to integrate them into my ASP.NET Core Blazor application. My hesitation stems from uncertainty about the most appropriate approach and concerns regarding scalability, efficiency, and data security.

Comment: See this  Gist  - https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ba16f6bb6934842d78c89ab5314f4b56 And this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913396/how-to-store-session-data-in-server-side-blazor.   Note that any answer cannot take into account "My hesitation stems from uncertainty about the most appropriate approach and concerns regarding scalability, efficiency, and data security." as we have no understanding of what you are doing and therefore any answer will be opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side storage - is a **good way**! I will just rephraze your claim to make it more specific - **frontend storage is a good way**.

The reason for rephrazing is latency. When you work with frontend - the latency is a measure of quality of service (QoS), so faster calls - means faster UI/API, better UX. So your storage have these requirements:

1. *It should have really fast lookup*. Any `Cloud Tables` or `redis` is what comes to mind. `Redis` is better because you can subscribe backend to latest updates instead of implementing notification yourself. Worst decision is SQL, transactions are bad for latency.
2. *It should be as close as possible to frontend*. Same region, maybe subnet, maybe machine, etc. Same region is usually fast enough from my experience in scaled systems, +20ms wont do a thing to latency.

This way your frontend will be fast, backend can be in any latency range and you also get a shared state between frontends (can freely scale frontend up/down, perform new releases and generally do maintenance tasks on your servers without loosing user session). So your user can , for example, switch between mobile site version, mobile app, desktop site, at the time you deploy new release and user can still have access to his settings.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems that using Redis might indeed be the most suitable approach. Consider the following scenario:

User logs in.

They input values into the designated boxes, which are then transferred to Redis.

The user clicks on the calculate button.

Here lies the issue: I have a class named WorkingData, which contains attributes like this:

    public static double elp = double.NaN;
In the event that two or more users are logged in and simultaneously click the calculate button, will the value of elp be overwritten by the actions of other users?

Comment: In redis you are free to create your own compound keys. The key can be per-user, per-service, per-something-else. If you want shared state - you use shared key "my:shared:path:elp". If you want per user info - you create compound key, something like "my:path:to:users:123:variables:foobar".