# SessionStorage sometimes lost after navigating away and coming back

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I'm using SessionStorage to store private contextual information needed for my frontend application. I have noticed that sometimes when navigating away to a different website (different domain, part of the application flow) and coming back again, the session storage is not the way I left it. Sometimes there is nothing, sometimes a couple of properties still remain.

I have seen this happen on Chrome incognito on Windows, and Safari private browsing mode. For Safari, I can detect private browsing and fall back on session cookies, however these will be pointlessly passed over the network so I don't want to make this my main solution. Also I can only detect it for Safari and not for Chrome.

I cannot find any articles stating this is expected behaviour. The fact that it does not always occur makes it even more fun to debug.

Is there a way to reliably use SesionStorage? Or are there any suggested alternatives for storing this sensitive information in a secure way?

Answer (score 0):

No a SessionStorage is bound to the lifetime of a browsing context. This context is different between browsers.
From the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-sessionstorage-attribute):

> The lifetime of a browsing context can be unrelated to the lifetime of the actual user agent process itself, as the user agent can support resuming sessions after a restart.

If you want a more persistent solution you can use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalStorage instead of using Session Storage
But do not forget to clear the local storage when you do not need to store data further
for more information [check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage)

Comment: LocalStorage 'leaks' between tabs and is also not bound to the user Session, which means closing the tab will not clear the storage, which is bad for private information