# How can I determine if the page is loaded in a new window or tab?

Tags: javascript

I have a gallery website with paintings that scrolls from left to right with `overflow-x: scroll`.

When the user clicks on a painting, the current scroll position is stored in `localStorage` and the detail page is shown. When the user clicks the back button, the scroll position is being set when the page is loaded.

I want this scroll position to be unset when the page is being loaded in a new tab or window. How can I tell if this happened?

Unsetting on page reload is already working. But opening the website in a new window does not count as a reload apparently.

I have tried reading the `sessionStorage`, but that doesn't do the trick.

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1 || sessionStorage.isNewSession) {
   localStorage.setItem("scrollPositionHome", 0);
}
```

`performance.navigation.type` sees it's a page reload, `sessionStorage.isNewSession` isn't doing much.

Comment: show what you tried please.

Comment: Edited my original post

Comment: I just figured out I forgot to set the `isNewSession` variable. Be right back, smacking myself in the head.

Comment: Oh, it's still not working as expected. When I open the website in a new window the scroll position is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`. You can find a small explanation following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5523174/9850995).

TL;DR: `sessionStorage` is per tab and `localStorage` will persist over multiple sessions. You could just empty your `localStorage` or use the `sessionStorage` in the first place.

If you could provide some code, we can give you a more thorough explanation / help.

Comment: I guess I had a brain fart. Your suggestion is the solution. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could right your own code to open links!

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    // This will prevent the default behaviour 
    e.PreventDefault();
    // On Control click it's opened in a new window
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey){
    // Open in new window, you can already reset your localstorage here.
    localStorage.setItem("scrollPositionHome", 0);
    window.open(e.target.href);    
     } else {
    // Just a simple redirect
    window.location.href = e.target.href;
    }
});
```

**NOTE: This is not tested! I will correct this if needed!**

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. The scroll position needs to be reset when the website is opened in a new tab or window, not from an action on the website.

Comment: Well, you overwrite the logic on opening links. So as you can see in the comments of the code. If a control click is noticed, clear the LS then open it.

Comment: @Bronathan gave me the correct answer, thanks for your input!

Comment: No problem, it is indeed a better solution!