# How should i store newly created elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-storage

I running in some issues with my code below. I have achieved to create a new element and add it to the Option list. Now a whenever i refresh the page the new element will disappear from the list.I am not familiar how cookies or session works in JavaScript. But how could i store those element and whenever i create a new element to be able to be in the Option list even after refreshing. Sorry for my English , and thank you for the help in advance. My code is below as you can see.

```
    <select name="name" id="name">

        <option value="burim" class="someName">burim</option>
        <option value="eliot" class="someName">eliot</option>
        <option value="saska" class="someName">saska</option>

    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="add">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD list" id="btn">
    <p class="output"></p>

<script>
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick=function(){

    var n =document.getElementById("name");
    var list=document.getElementById("add").value;
    var listArray={};
    var newOption=document.createElement("option");

    listArray=n;

        newOption.className="someName";
        newOption.innerHTML=list;
        newOption.value=list;

    n.appendChild(newOption);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is three ( main ) way to store client side data in Javascript. 
The cookies are used to store data that is accessible to the server, ex: JWT authentication token.

The other two are Session storage and local storage. I've never learn the difference between the two but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5523140/5784924) is a good question about it.

In your case, I would suggest using `localStorage`. It is very easy to use and will be available until clear programmatically or by the user.

You can add data to the `localStorage` using

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key', value)
```

and retreive it using.

```
window.localStorage.getItem('key')
```

You should only keep minimum data in the `localStorage`, don't store your HTML. Store only enough data to rebuild it once you need your information.

Comment: Local storage persists, where as Session storage is cleared when the page session ends.