# Jquery Get Dropdown Label and make the default select option item placeholder

Tags: jquery, select, placeholder

I've inherited some php that deals with a dropdown select and need to make one small change: to move the label so that it becomes the default dropdown placeholder (instead of the first option).  I could modify the php file, but it may receive an automated update at some point, and then I'd have to modify it again.  Instead, I'd like to use jquery to move the label. I've searched the forums and have not quite been able to find what I'm looking for and get it to work.

The code I have inherited looks similar to this;

```
<form id="currency_converter">
 <label for="currency_switcher" class="currency_switcher_label">Choose a Currency</label>
  <select id="currency_switcher" class="currency_switcher select">
      <? foreach ( $currencies as $currency ) {
       $html .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $currency ) . '">'</option>';
      } ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

Which looks something like this :

[image]

However, I would like it to show the "Choose a Currency" as the first value / placeholder in the dropdown.

This is what I have but not working:

```
$("#currency_converter select").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).prev("label").text();
    $(this).children("option[selected='selected']").val(text).text(text);
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle I'm working on:  It works, but it replaces the first dropdown entry and I want to prepend not replace....

http://jsfiddle.net/clappertrapp/79uxp4rt/

Comment: We can't use a label as an option. You can create a new option with that default value at the start.

Comment: @palaѕн Updated - see the fiddle that shows that using label is working - so please explain what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works, but it replaces the first dropdown entry and I want to prepend not replace....

You can simply do this using [`prepend`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method instead and also need to use `.prop("selected", true)` so that it is selected by default on page load also:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#currency_converter select").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).prev("label").text();
    var $option = $("<option />").attr("value", text).text(text).prop("selected", true)
    $(this).prepend( $option )
  }).prev().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="currency_converter">
  <label for="currency_switcher" class="currency_switcher_label">Choose a Currency</label>
  <select id="currency_switcher" class="currency_switcher select">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
    <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Yup, that's the one :-)  Works fine now, thank you @palash  The only small issue is that the "choose a currency" remains the selected item if you navigate to another page.  So - if I choose USD how can I keep that as the in-focus / selected item that shows and persists across pages?  Is that possible or will it need a cookie?

Comment: You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) for that. Also, check out [HTML5 Local storage vs. Session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5523140)